# Unexpected output of Linear Regression

Tags: ocaml, linear-regression

I am implementing linear regression using gradient descent according to what I found on a blog. It seems to work for the small values but for larger values the output shoots up!.
Below is my implementation

```
let inps = [1.;2.;4.;3.;5.]
let targs = [1.;3.;3.;2.;5.]

let train inps targs = 
  let rec aux inps targs n slope intercept i = 
  match n with 
  | 0 -> [intercept;slope]
  | n ->
    let inp = List.nth inps i in 
    let output = inp*.slope +. intercept in 
    let error = (List.nth targs i) -. output in 
    let slope' = slope +. 0.01*.error*.inp in 
    let intercept' = intercept +. 0.01*.error in
    aux inps targs (n-1) slope' intercept' ((i+1) mod (List.length inps))
  in 
  aux inps targs 200 0. 0. 0
```

It works fine for the above `inps` and `targs` and the output is

```
utop # train inps targs;;
- : float list = [0.274637254235572281; 0.845725879951186532]
```

But when I change the `inps`, it gives incorrect and very large values

```
utop # let inps' = List.map (function x -> x*.10.) inps;;
val inps' : float list = [10.; 20.; 40.; 30.; 50.]
─( 22:53:28 )─< command 141 >────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # train inps' targs;;
- : float list = [9.50572250044365676e+69; 4.58043753555103929e+71]
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your implementation is not really a gradient descent, but a form of multigradient descent where you are trying to consecutively reduce the distance between the model and the data at a given point rather than the global distance.

Second, uses of List.nth are often a sign that you want an array rather than a list.

Third, overshooting is classical issue with gradient descent when the step size is too big. The issue is accentued here by the fact that you choose a constant γ =0.01 for the step size factor, with your next point defined as:

```
x_{n+1} = x_n - γ ∇F_n(x_n)
```

In your case, the further away you are from the minimum, the greater is the gradient and the longer is the next jump. Consequently, these jumps oscillate around the minimum without ever converging. For instance, printing the intermediary values of intercept and slope yields

```
0.010000,0.100000
0.019900,0.298000
-0.069499,-3.277960
0.934584,26.844530
-12.447027,-642.236005
51.911044,1.344703
51.152993,-13.816317
56.197990,187.983555
-0.739057,-1520.127837
759.382253,36485.937627
-2896.795332,-75.838225
-2852.629734,807.473742
```

The solution is to either manually reduce your step size or implement a better line search subalgorithm.